# How do I retrieve data from multiple tables (PostgreSQL) in Java Servlet?

Tags: java, postgresql, servlets

I having difficulties on retrieving data from multiple tables. It is going to be a search form and its a relational database.

**Question1:** How do I retrieve data from multiple tables now?

**Question2:** At the same time another problem I face is that I can not get any results if I try to search only by Name or Lastname. I get results only when I use date of birth. Why?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        Connection conn = null;{ // while there is no connections, proceed to the next step
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver"); // importing the driver to use the getConnection method
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/caglar", "postgres", //?searchpath=cag
                    "abracadabra");
            System.out.println("Connected to the database"); // console message
            String  agent_name  = request.getParameter("givenname"); // variable - reads from user input
            String  agent_lastname  = request.getParameter("familyname"); // variable - reads from user input
            String  dob  = request.getParameter("birthyear"); // variable - reads from user input

            ArrayList al=null;
            ArrayList agent_list =new ArrayList();

            //Problem 1: If dob is not given, it is not searching by name or lastname.

            //String query = "select * from agent where givenname='"+agent_name+"' or familyname='"+agent_lastname+"' or birthyear='"+dob+"' order by givenname";

            String query = "select * from agent where givenname='"+agent_name+"' or familyname='"+agent_lastname+"' ";
            if(dob!=null && !"".equals(dob)) // if date of birth fiel is left blank, it will still proceed to the results page
              query = query + " or birthyear='"+dob+"'"; // if date of birth exists, it will take it into account as well

            query = query+  "order by givenname"; // ordering by first name


            System.out.println("query" + query); // console message
            Statement st = conn.createStatement(); // connection statement
            ResultSet  rs = st.executeQuery(query); // executing our query


            while(rs.next())
            {
                al  = new ArrayList();

              al.add(rs.getString(1));//id
              al.add(rs.getString(2));//dob
              al.add(rs.getString(3));//name
              al.add(rs.getString(4));//lastname
              System.out.println("al :: "+al);
              agent_list.add(al);
            }

            request.setAttribute("agentList",agent_list);
```

Comment: Woah, that code is EXTREMELY vulnerable to SQL injection. Imagine what happens if someone submits a givenname of: (without double quotes) "myname'; DROP TABLE agent;--". You need to at bare minimum be using parameterized queries.

Comment: While not a direct answer, I strongly suggest that you check out (a) Facelets/JSF2 and (b) JPA2. Anyway, please show the query text you're producing from the working and non-working test cases.

Comment: Presumably, if DoB isn't given it's not matching anything. That implies that your givenname/lastname WHERE clause is always evaluating to false. Why is hard to say without the data. It could be case sensitivity, quoting, or all sorts of things.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/327  - just sayin'

Comment: You mean query this: CREATE TABLE agent
(
  agentid serial NOT NULL,
  birthyear numeric(4),
  familyname character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  givenname character varying(255) NOT NULL
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
ALTER TABLE agent OWNER TO postgres;

Comment: @krest I'm not sure what you were trying to say with the comment immediately above. Re SQL injection I'm talking about the query in your code beginning "select * from agent". To learn about SQL injection start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection and here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java

Comment: Do you think I can request data from the database without creating an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reiterate what the  others are pointing out above, this is "dangerous" code. By not using PreparedStatements, you are opening up yourself to SQL Injection attacks - by which, a malicious user can craft a SQL statement to delete all the data in a table. As @craig-ringer points above, it would be trivial submit data that would delete the table from the database.

Having pointed that out, underlined it several times and highlighted it in a fluorescent yellow mark, lets move on and try to answer your questions:

1) You can query data from multiple tables by using SQL Joins. [Here's a PostgreSQL tutorial on JOINS](http://www.postgresqlguide.com/retrieving-data-from-multiple-tables-by-using-sql-join.aspx) - there are many others out there, I just picked the first one I found.

2) Without the exact data in the database, and the exact parameters being supplied, it is difficult to answer - however, I imagine that the issue is case sensitivity. Comparisons in PostgreSQL are case sensitive - so if the family name in the database is 'Smith' and the parameter is 'smith', no data will be found. So, for simplicity, you'll need to covert both the parameter and the data to the same case e.g. lower. e.g. SELECT * FROM agent where LOWER(familyname)='smith'

I'd also point out that you may run into problems with date formatting - again, this would be addressed using prepared statements.

It appears you are quite new to java, SQL and JDBC;  I would suggest you try and follow some tutorials and read some books. There's quite a lot to get to grips with - good luck!

Comment: Note that a join isn't always the best way to retrieve data sets from multiple tables. Unless it's all neat 1:1 relationships you'll often have to de-duplicate content. I frequently prefer to just fetch from one table, then go and fetch from another table in another SELECT. Whether it's faster than the join varies a lot depending on round trip time vs bandwidth vs cpu cost etc, but it's sure a lot nicer to read and often easier on the DB. Looks like PostgreSQL will be able to return structured JSON or YAML query results soon anyway :-)

Comment: how do you do that twice Craig?